# React Native JSX: Setting state causes app to crash

Tags: react-native, state, reactjs

I am using react native to build my app. Below is the code I am using to display a list of 'tags'. So the code is used to hide all the tags except for the first 2, and a 'load more' link will appear. Clicking on the load more link is supposed to show the rest of the tags. However the code crashes on me.

```
this.state = {
  visibleCount: 2,
};

<TextLink onPress={() => {
    this.setState({visibleCount: mealTags.length});
  }}
</TextLink>
```

I am using changing to state to show the tags. Can anyone advise me on what went wrong and how I can update it?

```
export function MealTagsSection(props: MealTagsProps) {
  let {mealTags} = props;
  let loadMoreLink;

  if (mealTags.length > 2) {
    loadMoreLink = (
      //THIS CAUSES THE APP TO CRASH
      <TextLink onPress={() => {
        this.setState({visibleCount: mealTags.length});
      }}
      >
        load more...
      </TextLink>
    );
  } else {
    loadMoreLink = null;
  }

  this.state = {
    visibleCount: 2,
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.mealTagsContainer}>
      {
        mealTags.slice(0, this.state.visibleCount).map((mealTag) => {
          let tagStyle = '';
          if (mealTag.category === 1) {
            tagStyle = styles.tag_healthy;
          } else {
            tagStyle = styles.tag_improve;
          }
          return (
            <View style={tagStyle}>
              <Text style={styles.tagText}>{mealTag.description}</Text>
            </View>
          );
        })
      }
      {loadMoreLink}
    </View>
  );
}
```

The error I am getting is this:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: t.setState is not a function. (In 't.setState({visibleCount:n.length})', 't.setState' is undefined)', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: t.setState is not a function. (In 't.setState({visi..., stack: onPress@439:2034

Comment: Don't mutate state directly, call `this.setState`

Comment: Thanks @AndrewLi, after changing I am getting this error: 2017-05-26 11:30:24.419 Fulfilled[31978:2275669] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: t.setState is not a function. (In 't.setState({visibleCount:n.length})', 't.setState' is undefined)', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: t.setState is not a function. (In 't.setState({visi..., stack:
onPress@439:2034

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MealTagsSection` is a functional component. React functional component doesn't have to way to include a local state. If want to have local a state then you should make it a class component.

```
export class MealTagsSection extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { visibleCount: 2 };
  }

  render() {
    let { mealTags } = this.props;
    let loadMoreLink;

    if (mealTags.length > 2) {
      loadMoreLink =
        (
          <TextLink
            onPress={() => {
              this.setState({ visibleCount: mealTags.length });
            }}
          >
            load more...
          </TextLink>
        );
    } else {
      loadMoreLink = null;
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.mealTagsContainer}>
        {mealTags.slice(0, this.state.visibleCount).map(mealTag => {
          let tagStyle = "";
          if (mealTag.category === 1) {
            tagStyle = styles.tag_healthy;
          } else {
            tagStyle = styles.tag_improve;
          }
          return (
            <View style={tagStyle}>
              <Text style={styles.tagText}>{mealTag.description}</Text>
            </View>
          );
        })}
        {loadMoreLink}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```